# T test confidence interval

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, confidence-interval

For the t test we have $D = \frac{\bar{X}-\bar{Y}-\delta}{\sqrt{\frac{S_c^2}{n_1}+\frac{S_c^2}{n_2}}}$, where $\delta = \mu_1-\mu_2$ and $S_c^2$ is the combined sample variance.

When finding the confidence interval for $\delta$ we do: $$(t_{n_1+n_2-2, 0.025}<D<t_{n_1+n_2-2,0.975})$$

However when solving this I get $$(\bar{X}-\bar{Y}-t_{n_1+n_2-2,0.975}\sqrt{\frac{S_c^2}{n_1}+\frac{S_c^2}{n_2}}, \bar{X}-\bar{Y}-t_{n_1+n_2-2, 0.025}\sqrt{\frac{S_c^2}{n_1}+\frac{S_c^2}{n_2}})$$

Whereas my lecturer gets $$(\bar{X}-\bar{Y}+t_{n_1+n_2-2,0.025}\sqrt{\frac{S_c^2}{n_1}+\frac{S_c^2}{n_2}}, \bar{X}-\bar{Y}+t_{n_1+n_2-2, 0.975}\sqrt{\frac{S_c^2}{n_1}+\frac{S_c^2}{n_2}})$$

I've tried this multiple times, and it seems to me that my solution is correct. However my lecturer uses the other one throughout the text. So I wonder how mine can be wrong, even though it is just algebra. Which one is correct and why?

Comment: Actually I take my comment back.  What do you mean by your lecturer used the other one??

Comment: Throughout all the exercises solutions or the theory, whenever we had to find the confidence interval, he would get the second one. As you see the difference is both in the sign (mine is minus, his is plus) and in the "quintiles", indeed on the lowerbound I have the $0.975$ quintiles, and on the upperbound I have a $0.025$ quintile. In my lecturer's formula he always get the opposite instead

Comment: I see.  What happens when you use the same values for both formulas.. I mean, are the interval bounds different among the same input values or do both formulas arrive at the same interval when using the same input values  ??

Comment: They arrive at different interval bounds! Indeed I was trying to go through the problem and I failed all the intervals because of this formula. However the $\delta$ in the formula has a negative sign, so it is clear that at a certain point you'll have to multiply by $-1$ both sides, which will change the sign of inequality and will also give a negative sign to the quintiles of the $t$ distribution, so I really don't know how he got there

Comment: In many texts, the subscripts on cut-off points are _not_ quantiles, they are percentages cut from the _right_ tail of the distr'n. Thus in the t table I'm looking at the value that cuts .025 from the upper tail of $T(df=10)$ is $t_{.025} = 2.228.$ This is quantile .975; in R, `qt(.975, 10)` returns 2.228139. Since this is a symmetrical dist'n, quantile .025 (cutting 2.5% from the _lower_ tail) is -2.228139. If $D \sim T(10),$ then $P(L=-2.228 < D \le U=2.228) \approx 0.95.$ // Doing the algebra to get CI involves multiplying the inequality by $-1$ so $-U$ winds up in the _lower_  conf. limit.

Comment: If that is not enough explanation, leave a Comment. I have sleep and appointments for the next 18 hrs, but then I'll look back to see how it's going. Or maybe someone else will have helped by then.

Comment: yeah you were right, indeed, being the $t$ distribution symmetric we have that $t_{m_1+n_2-2, 0.025} = -t_{n_1+n_2-2}$, so the two formulas should be equal! I probably messed up somewhere in my calculations!